# Vowpal Wabbit: How to use command line arguments when splitting to train and test files

Tags: data-science, vowpalwabbit

I'm pretty new to VW, and wanted to verify my actions in the way i use the command line arguments..

I divided my data set into train set and test set (based on 75%-25%) and now want to run VW.

The command line arguments i used:

## Train set

> vw train.tsv -f model.vw --sgd --loss_function logistic --hash all
> --learning_rate 0.01 --power_t 0.0 --noconstant -b 22 --ignore 'A'

## Test set

> vw test.tsv -t -i model.vw -p preds.txt --sgd --link logistic --hash
> all --learning_rate 0.01 --power_t 0.0 --noconstant -b 22

I'm not sure if this part is needed in the test part:

> --hash all --learning_rate 0.01 --power_t 0.0 --noconstant -b 22

due to its presence in the model built in the train part.

Help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues with the attempted examples in the question above.

Let's explain this in steps.
Start simple, with a minimal working example:

#### training:

```
# Read training data from train.dat, learn
# and store the resulting model in train.model
vw -d train.dat -f train.model
```

#### testing:

```
# use the train.model to predict on new test.dat data
# output the predictions into predict.dat
vw -t -i train.model -d test.dat -p predict.dat
```

#### Notes:

- `train.dat` and `test.dat` must be in `vw` input format (they can't be `*.tsv`). There's a utility to convert csv/tsv to `vw` format.  Look for `utl/csv2vw` in the source tree.
- Note the use of `-d ...` to pass the input file argument to `vw`. Some older versions of `vw` were more lenient about having to specify `-d`, but recent versions are stricter. To be safe, just add `-d` before the input file.
- `vw` input format is [documented here](https://github.com/VowpalWabbit/vowpal_wabbit/wiki/Input-format)
- As you noticed: some of the options used during training, need not be passed during testing, since they are already embedded in the model (and can't be changed). For example the number of bits `-b 22` is one of these.  But you don't need to memorize which options. `vw` will print an error if options that it already knows about (from the model) are inconsistent or duplicated.  Just drop the ones you get an error message about.
- `-t` means test-only. By default `vw` will keep learning and update the model in memory.
- `-i` (load initial model) and `-f` (store final model) are used for reading a model file (at start) and writing a model file (at end) of run.
- Generally, since `vw` is an online learner, there's no need to split the data into train and test. Every example will be used for both a) prediction and b) learning.  Since prediction comes before the update of the model, all online predictions losses are test-like (out-of-sample)
- `--power_t 0` is an extreme setting and probably not what you want, it will keep forgetting what was learned (assume extreme non-stationarity of the data)
- You may add options like `--loss_function logistic` if the labels are in `{-1, 1}` and you're interested in logistic regression.
- `--hash-all` makes sense only if you have feature-names that are numbers and others which are not, and you want to minimize collisions.
- `--sgd` disables the SGD algorithm enhancements: `--adaptive`, `--normalized`, & `--invariant`. In most cases this makes convergence less robust and slower. Consider dropping this option.
- In most cases the `vw` default options work well. Change them only if you understand the option and know what you're doing.

There are some new and improved tutorials on the new Vowpal Wabbit site [vowpalwabbit.org](https://vowpalwabbit.org). The beginner's sections and examples are very good in my experience.